# Infinite loop in slide puzzle algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, infinite-loop

Trying to write an algorithm that solves a slide puzzle and I've been having issues, thought I'd come here for advice. This is on the princeton Algorithms, Part 1 course btw.

So I'll try to explain the logic then show the code. Basically I have a min priority queue of Search Nodes. Each search node has a board, a previous board, a number of moves to get to that board, and a manhattan priority (number of moves + manhattan distance)

Each pass through the while(true) loop deletes the minimum node (smallest priority), and adds new nodes whose previous node is the deleted node, board is a neighbor board (1 move away) from the deleted node, and moves 1 greater than the previous node.

Eventually, the deleted node is supposed to have the solved board, and then the shortest path can be found by looping through the previous nodes of the solved node. But this is never happening. I don't know if I have flaws in my logic, or if something in my code is off. But I've been trying to figure it out for a long time and have been getting nowhere.

I should mention that each slide puzzle is a 2d array, with 0 corresponding to the blank space.

Here is the Node class:

```
private class Node {
        Node previous;
        Board board;
        int moves;
        int priority;

        Node(Node previous, Board board, int moves) {
            this.previous = previous;
            this.board = board;
            this.moves = moves;
            priority = moves + board.manhattan();
        }
    }
```

This is the comparator I used to compare nodes. A node is smaller than another node if its priority is smaller.

```
// compares nodes based on their Manhattan priority
    private Comparator<Node> priority() {
        return (o1, o2) -> {
            return Integer.compare(o1.priority, o2.priority);
        };
    }
```

And here is the Solver constructor which is supposed to solve the slide puzzle. This currently assumes the puzzle is solvable. The while(true) loop is what's giving me issues and I don't know why.

```
// find solution to the initial board using A* algorithm
    public Solver(Board initial) {
        // define the first Node
        Node first = new Node(null, initial, 0);
        // enqueue neighbors into MinPQ
        MinPQ<Node> pq = new MinPQ<>(priority());
        for (Board board : first.board.neighbors()) {
            pq.insert(new Node(first, board, 1));
        }

        while (true) {
            // delete min node
            Node min = pq.delMin();
            // if it is the goal board, stop
            if (min.board.isGoal()) {
                break;
            }
            // add neighbors to pq
            for (Board board : min.board.neighbors()) {
                Node neighborNode = new Node(min, board, min.moves + 1);
                // don't add grandfather nodes
                if (!min.previous.board.equals(neighborNode.board)) {
                    pq.insert(neighborNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Step one is to make sure that `Board.isGoal()` works as expected - if it's broken, your loop will never end.  Step two is to run this through a debugger and follow along with the algorithm to see where your mistake is.

Comment: What do you do if your current board position matches a previous board position?  You can only get an infinite loop if you are repeating positions.  You probably need to detect a repeated position and take action to avoid the loop.

Comment: I would also remove the 1st for loop, and place the first node directly in the queue, with 0 moves. This allows you to finish in 0 moves, as expected, if your initial board is already solved.